# Arduino code for password-activated output through bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I have this pretty simple task to light up an LED for 3 seconds when I send the right password from my Android phone to the Arduino via Bluetooth. Below's the code I am using:

Setting up variables:

```
int output = 9;         //Pin 9 on arduino (LED)
char final[4];
char correct[4] = {'Q','W','E','R'}; //Password is QWER
int pass_true;

void setup() {
  pinMode(output, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);

}
```

Here's the code in question:

```
void loop() {
  while(Serial.available()){
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
      final[i] = Serial.read();
    }
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
      if(final[i]==correct[i]){
        pass_true = 1;
      }
      else{
        pass_true = 0;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  if(pass_true==1){
    digitalWrite(output, HIGH);
    Serial.println("ON");
    delay(3000);
    pass_true = 0;
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(output, LOW);
  }

}
```

As a newbie I can't see what's wrong with this code. I don't get any response from the arduino when sending the correct password. The LED doesn't turn on, the device doesn't return any Serial.println() string.

I see to it that the electrical part is all good so I'm pretty sure the problem is with the code. I am using Bluetooth spp pro Android app.

Comment: I already posted the same question on arduino.stackexchange.com I'm so desperate I'm asking this here as well.

Comment: First of all it's not very polite to post it twice... However there are a couple of issues. First of all you are not filtering the input (i.e. removing the new lines, if any). Then you are not going into timeout. If, for instance, you send QW and then your app crashes, you will never be able to turn it on again. Third thing: you'd better set `pass_true = 1;` BEFORE starting the `i = [0,4)` loop, otherwise any password ending with R will trigger the led (also AZER, BLUR, CHER, ROAR....)